# CakePHP: COUNT function and model joining help

Tags: sql, cakephp, join, controller, models

I'm trying to join tables to get a count on a field but am having trouble figuring out how to do it. here are my tables:

```
tags
id     INT
tag    VARCHAR

project_tags
id         INT
project_id INT
tag_id     INT

projects
id     INT
...
```

I want show in my view something like this:

```
[tags.tag] x 23
[tags.tag] x 12
...
```

Now I'm no SQL expert but I think what I'd be aiming for in SQL would be performing count on tag_id where tag_id = tags.id grouped by tag_id. I think.

I'm just now so sure how to do this in a cake controller.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps send this query to the database:

```
 SELECT t.tag, COUNT(*) AS NumOccurrances
 FROM project_tags pt 
 INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
 GROUP BY  t.tag
 ORDER BY 2 DESC  --sorting by count.
```

In your controller, execute ad-hoc SQL:

```
$results = $this->Tag->query("select ...");
```

[More on CakePHP querying a database](http://www.devdaily.com/php/php-cakephp-database-sql-query-select). Perhaps roll this up into a [stored procedure in MySQL, and call from your Cake controller](http://frodosghost.com/2009/04/02/using-mysql-stored-procedures-in-cakephp/).

```
$results = $this->query("CALL MyStoredProc");
```

Comment: thanks p.campbell, I'm getting an error though. my code looks like this:   $this->set('tags', $this->query('SELECT t.tag, COUNT(*) AS NumOccurrances FROM project_tags pt INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id GROUP BY  t.tag ORDER BY 2 DESC'));
But i'm getting an error: Call to undefined method PagesController::query() I think its because it's a method of Model. But there is no model for projects_tags so not sure what to do here

Comment: @Jonesy: Try replacing `$this->query` with `$this->Tag->query`, as you noticed, query is a method of Model, not Controller class. If you have a Tag model, use that, it should work.

Comment: @dr : thanks for the tip. From those articles, it seemed to suggest that `$this->query();` was recommended for ad-hoc, but perhaps you've got it.

Comment: Thanks! also, I did $this->Projects->query() and everthing works alright. so it can be any old model?

Comment: @Jonesy: indeed, substitute the table name there, and off you go!